# What feature of Racket makes it good for Language Engineering?

Tags: racket, dsl

It can often be read that Racket has some outstanding features, which make Racket very good for language engineering.

For somebody who does not know Racket or Lisp, this not clear. It is really hard to catch that information when reading through the Internet.

What feature or features make Racket so special with regard to language engineering?

Let me clarify what sort of information I am searching.

Each programming language has a specific syntax, specific language constructs or control structures. These things make a language good in some situations or bad in other situations. It is often relatively clear that this is the case, even if you don't understand much of a language. For example you can say, that Ada is good for safety related software, because it has a very strong typing system, that forces from the developer to clarify certain aspects of the program code that are then verified at compile time.

But Racket is a Lisp. It looks very similar to other Lisp languages. Without knowing Lisp, I don't see what is so unique to Racket and why Racket is more appropriate for DSLs than other Lisp languages.

It seems that for a language being a Lisp language does not mean a lot. You can easily compare Python or C++. C++ for example wants you to write all these curly braces in order to clarify what is your scope and it wants you to define types in order to specify your code. Both makes C++ a good candidate for you if you are a fan of procedural programming (but obviously not a unique selling point). That is something, which even people can understand, who don't know exactly what these words mean in Python or C++.

But you cannot so easily compare one Lisp languages with another Lisp language. At least I cannot. This is why I am asking. Each Lisp languagues must also have certain uniquenesses. And I would like to know what are the uniquenesses of Racket that makes it a good solution for language engineering.

Comment: I think this is a reasonable question, but answers to it it will almost certainly be opinion-based, and so against the rules of SO.

Comment: I hope not. There must be something concrete, what Racket has and Common Lisp not. I don't think, that people come with answers "because Racket is more comfortable or Racket is more modern". There must be some unique selling point of Racket.

Comment: Yes, it's (much) more than a library. You might want to start with [Building Languages with Racket](https://www.cs.utah.edu/plt/dagstuhl19/), or [Defining new #lang Languages](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/hash-languages.html), or [this tutorial](https://beautifulracket.com/stacker/intro.html).

Comment: @habrewning: you could clearly *implement* Racket in CL (or Python, or ...) which means that there is never anything concrete and all questions like this are matters of style and opinion.

Comment: @ignisvolens I think you can reframe this question as asking about why Racket is *advertised* as being good for this purpose. That surely is less opinion-based than just polling the crowd. Regardless, I think voting to close this as "opinion-based" stretches the meaning of "opinion" too far, past the point that is necessary to avoid low-quality Q&A threads. Authoritative answers on this subject could be valuable contributions to the community.

Comment: @shadowtalker I think any good answer would be essentially a paper on comparative language design.  I'd personally be happy for such things to be on SO but whenever I've tried to add one I've been shot down by the mafia.  Now I'm trying to say they should not be here I'm being shot down by a different group of mafia :-)  So I have no real opinion: all I know is that the SO rules are too arcane for me to understand.

Comment: Racket provides a very elaborate macro system, and metaprogramming is exactly the tool you need to construct languages. Parsing is a trivial problem, any language can do it, but only meta-languages allow to compose new languages seamlessly from small pieces.

Comment: And yes, everything you can do in Racket is equally possible in Common Lisp and any other meta-language. They are all interchangeable.

Comment: @ignisvolens there are _plenty_ of papers on that topic, and on Racket specifically, which an authoritative answer can cite. I think even citing relevant portions of Racket docs, conference talks, blog posts, etc. would be useful.

Comment: May be, the answer will be something that the Common Lisp macro system only takes s-expressions. And the Racket macro system is more powerful and can take even strings that are not s-expressions. That would mean, the Common Lisp languages are always s-expression languages while Racket languages can be something else than s-expressions. That is pure speculation at the moment.

Comment: CL has read macros: ["The read macro is the device we use to process non-lisp syntax before the lisp reader gets its paws on it."](https://letoverlambda.com/index.cl/guest/chap4.html).

Answer (score 0):

According to the [racket manifesto](https://www2.ccs.neu.edu/racket/pubs/manifesto.pdf), which was written by the professors who designed Racket, Racket is a good language for making domain specific languages because it was designed with this purpose in mind.

for example, racket has a parser generator and other language engineering tools built into the standard library; the idea is that if you use racket you should not have to use external libraries to build a dsl.

Another reason racket is a great language for making dsls is because the racket designers designed their macro system specifically to design new languages; for example, the rackets loop comprehension, first class components, and class systems as such sub languages and yet you cant tell these sub languages apart from other features in racket.

the macros in racket were designed to define new languages instead of just extending the language.

anyways, theres more reasons but you should read the racket manifesto so you can get a better idea.